# 3D Plot - Step Function

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, 3d, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I would like to generate a 3D picture for a step function, something like this:

[image]

but I got stuck. Below, I tried something.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  % Draw the axes
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (8,0,0) node[below] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,8,0) node[left] {$z$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[above] {$x$};

  
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\numlevels}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\levelheight}{4}

 
  \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} {
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\numlevels} {
      \draw (\x,\y,0) -- (\x,\y,\levelheight) -- (\x+1,\y,\levelheight) -- (\x+1,\y,0) -- cycle;
      \draw (\x,\y,0) -- (\x,\y,\levelheight) -- (\x,\y+1,\levelheight) -- (\x,\y+1,0) -- cycle;
      \draw (\x,\y+1,0) -- (\x,\y+1,\levelheight) -- (\x+1,\y+1,\levelheight) -- (\x+1,\y+1,0) -- cycle;
      \draw (\x+1,\y,0) -- (\x+1,\y,\levelheight) -- (\x+1,\y+1,\levelheight) -- (\x+1,\y+1,0) -- cycle;
    }
  }


  \node[align=center] at (-0.5,-1.1,2) {\resizebox{!}{0.5\height}{\footnotesize{$b=x_{2}$}}};
  \node[align=center] at (1.2,1,3) {\resizebox{!}{0.5\height}{\footnotesize{$b=x_{1}$}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Any solution or idea would be very helpful!

Comment: Where did you get stuck, though? What is your question? You just need some real data.

Comment: what is exactly the formula for your 3D step function? I do not want to guess from your not-so-clear figure.